# kotlin save bitmap to jpg file

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm running on android 12
i can get bitmap from my function
but i can't find the file in the folder(Clip folder  was created by program successfully

this is my save function

```
 private val saveImageToFolder = View.OnClickListener {
        try {
            var fileName:String = "img" + imageName.text.toString() + ".jpg"
            var values:ContentValues = ContentValues()
            var path = "DCIM/Clip"

            val filePath = File(path)
            if(!filePath.exists()){
                filePath.mkdir()
            }

            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,fileName)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,path)
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
            } else {
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path)
            }

            val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!).use { output ->
                val bm: Bitmap = mixBitmap(paintViewList)
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output)
            }
        }
        catch (e:java.lang.Exception){
            Log.d("onBtnSavePng", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
i'm update IS_PENDING to 0 after compress the image, but it still not saved

```
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!).use { output ->
                var bm: Bitmap = mixBitmap(paintViewList)
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output)
                values.clear()
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)
                contentResolver.update(uri,values,null,null)
            }
```

Comment: Change to  if(!filePath.exists()){
               if(! filePath.mkdir()) return;
            }

Comment: But this mkdir will never create that Clip directory. Remove all the code as the insert() will create the directory.

Comment: `ediaColumns.DATA, path)
            }` In that case the value of path should be a full path.

Comment: You should use IS_PENDING twice.

Comment: @blackapps I move is_pending under the version check, but it still can't save image.

Comment: ???? You use it only once. You should use it TWICE.

Comment: @blackapps i need change is_pending to 0 after compress? i'm trying but it not work

Comment: We still cannot see that you use it twice.

Comment: @blackapps after update to android 13, the image I saved is appear, I don't know why it not appear after I update IS_PENDING(maybe there's some bug in my phone), but the problem is solved.thank you!